# Testing authenticated file uploads in merb

Tags: file-upload, rspec, mocking, merb

This is something that has been driving me mad over the past few days. I have an action which allows authenticated users to upload assets to the site. I know that the controller action is correct as I can run through the process manually however I want to test it using rspec.

I have to use the `request` helper so I can reuse an authenticated session which is a `:given` for this set of tests.

```
it "should allow authenticated file uploads" do
    file = File.open(a_valid_file)
    mock_file = mock("file")
    mock_file.stub!(:path).and_return(file.path)

    request( resource(:assets), :method => "POST",
        :params => { :file => 
            {:tempfile => mock_file, :filename => File.basename(file.path)} }
    )
end
```

If I breakpoint inside the spec it all works nicely, however when I run the spec and try to access the path in the controller action through the debugger I get this:

```
e file[:tempfile].path
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `path' for "#[Spec::Mocks::Mock:0x3fda2a4736c0 @name=\"file\"]":String
```

My guess is that the `stub!(:path)` is not being set for whatever mock object is making it through the request.

The question is: Am I going about the right way for testing file uploads and if not what is another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong. By using `request` it was calling to_s on all paramaters, so my mock object was being passed as "#[Spec::Mocks::Mock:0x3fda2a4736c0 @name=\"file\"]". That will teach me to pay more attention to exception output.

Instead I should use `multipart_post` and stub out the authentication calls in a block.

```
it "should allow authenticated file uploads" do
    file = File.open(a_valid_file)

    multipart_post( resource(:assets), :method => "POST", 
            :params => { :file => file } ) do |controller|
        controller.stub!(:ensure_authenticated).and_return(true)
        controller.session.stub!(:user).and_return(User.first)

    )
end
```